# Is '!!' an existing operator in C?

Tags: c, operators

While going over infrastructure code, I found this:

```
return !!(fin.flags & FIN_ACCEPT);
```

Does this has a meaning other than two logical nots in succession?

Comment: No. Take a look at any reference on "C operators".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!` is logical negation. `!!` is logical negation applied twice.

It is typically used to normalise a boolean expression value to be either `0` or `1`.

Comment: Also known as normalization of a truth-value.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to turn a numerical value into a boolean value. For example:

```
a = 5;
a = !!a;
```

!(!a)---> !(!5) ----> !(0) ----> 1

`a` will have value 1.

Comment: Check wheter the variable is version-controlled? Or what do you mean with revertability?